# Access specifiers in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I've the below code,

```
template< typename T >
class T1 { 
public:
    T i;
protected:
    T j;
private:
    T k;
    friend void Test();
};
```

The above code has a template class T1 with three members i,j and k and a friend function Test(),

I just want to know that which member/s of T1 will be available in function Test()?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to know that which member/s of T1 will be available in function Test()?

[`i,j and k`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function)

Comment: You mean all three i,j & k will be available in function Test()?

Answer (score 4):

All of them (i, j, k) will be available in function Test().

This is what "friend" gives you access to.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone. If it's friend it's friend for good and bad.