# Friend function and templates

Tags: c++, templates, scope, friend

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447773/access-specifiers-in-c/) question.

```
#include<iostream>
template< typename T >
class T1 {
public:
    T i;
    void display()
    {
       std::cout<<i<<"\n"<<j<<"\n"<<k; 
 }
protected:
    T j;
private:
    T k;
    friend void Test( T1 &obj);
};

template<typename T>
void Test(T1<T> &obj)
{
    T a=T();

    obj.i=a;
    obj.j=a;
    obj.k=a;
}


int main()
{
   T1<int>a;
   Test(a);
   a.display();
}
```

Why doesn't the above code compile?

Comment: Here: http://ideone.com/G6kcV. Read the note for yourself, it gives pretty detailed instructions

Comment: @jpalecek That's a very useful site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`friend void Test( T1 &obj);` declares a `non template` function.

Declare it as a `template`.

Try this :

```
....
private:
T k;
template<typename U>
  friend void Test( T1<U> &obj);
};
```